# R: multinom. Plenty of memory but still get memory error

Tags: r, multinomial

I am using 64 bit R (not RStudio)
I am getting the following error:

> > nounsResults <- multinom(Major1 ~ ., data = nouns, MaxNWts=120000)
> >     weights:  101332 (100521 variable)
> >     Error: cannot allocate vector of size 512 Kb

But I have plenty of memory available:
[image]

My code is a first attempt at multinomial logistic regression in R
(the multiple gc() calls is my panicking)

```
    library(foreign)
library(nnet)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

sink("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Dropbox\\__xx\\datafiles\\OutputR.txt", append=FALSE, split=TRUE)
gc()
memory.limit()


options(max.print=1000000)

nouns <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\xxx\\Dropbox\\__xx\\datafiles\\nouns-categorical_R1.csv")


#sapply(nouns,function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
gc()

nouns$Major1<-relevel(nouns$Major0, ref="ACCOUNTING")
nouns$Major1
gc()
nounsResults <- multinom(Major1 ~ ., data = nouns, MaxNWts=120000)
gc()
nounsResults
```

Comment: The error doesn't say "not enough available memory" it says "can't allocate a vector of size ..."

Comment: Yes, but research tells me it is related to available ram